# Integrating Wordpress with the existing react application

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog and hosted in the domain blog.domain.com now I want to move this my main domain which is domain.com/blog , the main domain run the web app which is built with react js and we use nginx as our web server to run both the application.

How can I integrate the Wordpress with the existing react application do let me know if you have done something on similar work.

We want to integrate the blogs which is  in wordpress as SEO friendly but we couldn't achieve it with react js  and WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to host the React app in WordPress using the ReactPress plugin which provides everything you need for it to work without custom build configurations. This will let you sort out your SEO whilst still hosting the functional React app.

[ReactPress Plugin Site](https://rockiger.com/en/reactpress/)